# Julia, use of map to run a function multiple times,

Tags: loops, integer, julia

I have some code that runs fine and does what I want, although there may be a simpler more elegant solution, this works :

```
round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250))))
```

However when I try to execute it multiple times, using map, it throws an error saying it doesn't like the Int16 specification, so this:

```
map(round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250)))), 1:2)
```

throws this error

```
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Int16 are not callable
```

I just want to run it twice (in this case) and sum the results.  Why is it unhappy?  Thx. J

Comment: @callmeSteve shows this in his answer, but I want to emphasize that you do not have to _first_ `floor` and afterwards `round`. Just directly `floor` to `Int16`. You can supply an integer type to all the rounding functions, like `floor`, `ceil`, `trunc`, `round`. No need to do wasteful extra work that takes more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `map` is a function. So, with your code, Julia is trying to make a function call:

```
round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250))))()
```

But the output of `round(Int16, ...)` isn't a function, it's a number, so you cannot call it. That's why the error says "objects of type Int16 are not callable." You could fix this by using an anonymous function:

```
map(() -> round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250)))), 1:2)
```

*But* the "Julian" way to do this is to use a comprehension:

```
[round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250)))) for _ in 1:2]
```

EDIT:

If you are going to `sum` the results, then you can use something that looks like a comprehension but is called a generator expression. This is basically everything above with the `[` `]` around the expression. A generator expression can be used directly in functions like `sum` or `mean`, etc.

```
sum(round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250)))) for _ in 1:2)
```

The advantage to generator expressions is that they don't allocate the memory for the full array. So, if you did this 100 times and used the `sum` approach above, you wouldn't need to allocate space for 100 numbers.

---

This goes beyond the original question, but OP wanted to use the `sum` expression where the `2` in `1:2` is a 1-element vector. Of course, if the input is always a 1-element vector, then I recommend `first(x)` like the comments. But this is a nice opportunity to show the importance of breaking things down into functions frequently in Julia. For example, you could take the entire `sum` expression and define a function

```
generatenumbers(n::Integer) = sum(... for _ in 1:n)
```

where `n` is a scalar. Then if you have some odd array expression for `n` (1-element vector, many such `n`s in a multi-dim array, etc.), you can just do:

```
generatenumbers.(ns)
# will apply to each element and return same shape as ns
```

If the de-sugaring logic is more complex than applying element-wise, you can even define:

```
generatenumbers(ns::AbstractArray) = # ... something more complex
```

The point is to define an "atomic" function that expresses the statement or task you want clearly, then use dispatch to apply it to more complicated data-structures that appear in practical code. This is a common design pattern in Julia (not the only option, but an effective one).

Comment: This last solution appears to work great until I use a variable to replace the `2` at the very end.  So `sum(round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250)))) for _ in 1:VAR1)` complains because VAR1 is a 1-element array of type Int64.  I tried to change it to Real or something else but no luck. Thx. J

Comment: This is a good answer imho. Better to use a generator than creating a vector and then summing it. As for `VAR1` being a 1-element array, don't use an array, then, use a scalar, changing element type does no good.

Comment: Thks both, learning Julia from R, where value in vector doesn't seem to matter.  I found something about `dot` function to convert from single element array to scalar but it doesn't seem to work, perhaps depricated?

Comment: The dot function has never been for that purpose, but there are many ways: `x[1]`, `first(x)`, `last(x)`, `only(x)`, `x[end]`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Adding on the answer from @darsnack.
**If** you want to run it multiple times in order to keep the results (it wasn't clear from the question). Then you could also ask rand to produce a vector by doing the following (and also making the type conversion through the floor call).

Moving from:

```
map(round(Int16, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250)))), 1:2)
```

to:

```
floor.(Int16, rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250), 2))
```

The documentation is [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Base.rand).

Comment: Yes, this a good suggestion that addresses the best way to do what OP might *actually* have wanted all along. +1